# Vue Lifecycle — which happens before page renders?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using Vue 2, I want to run a check before any page elements are rendered, to determine whether the user is signed in and if so, redirect them to another page.

Looking at the [Vue Lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html), it's my understanding that `beforeMount` is first in this cycle. However, the page still appears for half a second before redirecting (in my case, to `Dashboard`)

```js
beforeMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {  
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Dashboard'})
    }
  });
}
```

I've tried other Lifecycle options and none of the others work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using asynchronous operation and expect it to be instantly applied. This is what router hooks beforeRouteEnter/Update are for, and for global auth there's router.beforeEach. . You may want to revise your auth process because onAuthStateChanged subscription for one-time operation doesn't look ok.

Comment: @EstusFlask, ah I had no idea about those hooks. Thank you. What is the issue with the onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: @EstusFlask, I've got those hooks working now, but if I try and access a path directly (e.g. /dashboard, which requires auth), it allows it even if the user isn't auth'd, because it's not going through router. Is there a way I can set these hooks to work even when going direct?

Comment: "because it's not going through router" - I'm not sure what you mean. If it's router view, it always goes through a router and so through hooks. If you have a specific problem at this point, consider posting a question with the actual state of things.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Vue's lifecycle [diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram):

`beforeCreate` and `created` hooks are earlier than `beforeMount`. You should use either one of them.

Comment: It's correct, but the OP shouldn't use one of them because it used asynchronously

Comment: They don't work either — "I've tried other Lifecycle options and none of the others work either". I just tried again, and they still display the page for half a second before redirecting.

Comment: @EstusFlask, I've also tried making the various methods async, but it didn't seem to change anything

Comment: @Joseph You're missing the way Vue lifecycle works. Once you started to render a component, it will be rendered asap (unless you use Vue 3 suspense). If you don't want it to be rendered instantly, don't render it. This is what router hooks are for

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Guard for this. you have to check auth before going to route on `router.js` file. you can use `beforeEnter` into your route path.

read more about that here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard